# Block one specific URL by htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I could not find the solution to this question. Maybe I used the wrong search terms? *(htaccess block url, htaccess block single url, block specific url htaccess, ...)*

I have a page with a URL like this:

`https://www.mathelounge.de/40224/redaktionelle-frage-wann-antwort-wann-lediglich-kommentar`

I would like to block this URL because different bots (and humans).

I have tried the following rules within htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^40224\/$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

without success.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When someone requests:

```
https://www.mathelounge.de/40224/redaktionelle-frage-wann-antwort-wann-lediglich-kommentar
```

The `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable is:

```
/40224/redaktionelle-frage-wann-antwort-wann-lediglich-kommentar
```

And the regex `^40224\/$` will never match that. In fact, you don't even need a `RewriteCond` in this instance, just put the pattern in the rule:

```
RewriteRule ^40224/redaktionelle-frage-wann-antwort-wann-lediglich-kommentar$ - [F]
```

Note that the pattern in the rule itself doesn't lead with a `/`, it's because for the rule, it's stripped off, but for the `%{REQUEST_URI}` var, it's preserved.

Answer (score 1):

this can also be used:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} 40224/redaktionelle-frage-wann-antwort-wann-lediglich-kommentar [NC,OR]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!  Don't forget about formatting to help make your answers more readable.  You can check out a guide for markdown on Stackoverflow.  Cheers!  https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score -5):

Cant we disallow the URL on robots .txt and submit it. That would be a better way, I think.

Comment: How does that prevent humans from accessing the URL? Never mind that honoring the contents of ROBOTS.txt is completely optional and no bot is obligated to do so.