# How to block access to a particular route in .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, webserver

I need to block access to a particular route in my web application using a `.htaccess` file for everyone except a list of IP's. When I try to do it myself: block all and whitelist my IP's for a particular route it looks like this:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 1.1.1.1
allow from 2.2.2.2
```

I tried using the Location directive, but it is not allowed in `.htaccess`.

I do not have access to the server config file since it is a managed hosting provider.

The route I want to block is for eg: `http://www.example.com/route1`

Is there a way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Block one specific URL by htaccess. Cannot be that hard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173693/block-one-specific-url-by-htaccess-cannot-be-that-hard)

Comment: not sure I can do that using a rewriterule

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can definitely achieve this using multiple methods.

**.htaccess files**:

```
<files route1>
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
    allow from my.ip.address
</files>
```

Comment: @JeetendraPujari good stuff. Please accept my answer as the solution then by clicking the tick beside my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at whitelisting multiple ip's I would suggest the follow method:

```
<Files myfile.php>
  order deny,allow
  deny from all
  allow from env=allowip

  #Office 1
  #132.11.32.222
  SetEnvIf X-FORWARDED-FOR "^132\.11\.32\.222" allowip

  #Office 2
  #142.11.32.222
  SetEnvIf X-FORWARDED-FOR "^142\.11\.32\.222" allowip
</Files>
```