# Unable to restrict direct access to url in codeigniter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, web-testing

I have tried below methods to restrict direct access of file from URL but these are not working as when applied these changes in .htaccess whole websites stops working asking for 403 forbidden.i want if someone run ww.domainname.com/error_log/ it should restrict access and display 304 forbidden error.  I want to restrict some specific files for example:

- www.domainname.com/error_log/
- www.domainname.com/script/

  below are the code snippets I have tried to get the results but failed.

  ```
  <IfModule authz_core_module>
  Require all denied</IfModule>
  <IfModule !authz_core_module>
  Deny from all
  </IfModule>

  <Files ~ "\.(htaccess|php)$">
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
  </Files>
  ```

Comment: Nothing in that snippet seems to have any connection with what you said you tried to exclude.

Comment: i have googled for the same but no success. i want if someone directly hit the url it should show 304 forbidden error those are jus example. i want if someone run ww.domainname.com/error_log/ it should restrict access and display 304 forbidden error.

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/q/32334514/1427878 (And before you come back here with “doesn’t work!”, please go read [ask].)

Comment: @CBroe Thanks i will try this and get back to you soon. can we restrict access to the root folders without affecting live website?

Comment: This didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

Inside each folder you want to prevent access to create a .htaccess containing one line

```
Deny from all
```

www.domainname.com/error_log/.htaccess
www.domainname.com/script/.htaccess

Better yet, if your host allows it, move folders like logs and scripts to the folder above public_html so it's not possible for them to be served if you accidentally break your .htacces file in future.