# how to inactive selected URL from websites?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, .htaccess

```
<html>
<head>
<title>atoz</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<a href="www.hjk.com">hjk</a>
<a href="www.pqr.com">pqr</a>
<a href="www.abc.com">abc</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

> ### Please update:
>
> > Now i want to disable www.hjk.com URL link using javascript or css

Comment: use `a[href="www.xyz.com"] { pointer-events: none; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

In css way

```
a[href="www.xyz.com"] { 
   pointer-events: none; 
}
```

```css
a[href="www.xyz.com"] {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="www.xyz.com">xyz</a>
  <a href="www.pqr.com">pqr</a>
  <a href="www.abc.com">abc</a>
</div>
```

In Jquery

```js
$(function() {
  $("a[href='www.xyz.com']").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="www.xyz.com">xyz</a>
  <a href="www.pqr.com">pqr</a>
  <a href="www.abc.com">abc</a>
</div>
```

Comment: if i want to write same questions answer in .htaccess then how would i write this code

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173693/block-one-specific-url-by-htaccess-cannot-be-that-hard

Comment: @SagarMistry well if my answer is right please mark it as accepted ...see how here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work