# Block specific URL in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173693/block-one-specific-url-by-htaccess-cannot-be-that-hard) but, when i applied to my htaccess server... I can still browse my site without block.

My url : http://sub.domain.com/something/some-thing-url/

My code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sub.domain.com/something/some-thing-url$ - [F]
```

But didn't solve my problem..

Any kind of suggestion will be accept..

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to match against `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable in `RewriteCond` .

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^something/some-thing-url$ - [F]
```